# Properly installed Kivy on Pi3B won't exit or show mouse/cursor moves

Tags: python, raspbian-jessie

I have set up kivy to where I can successfully launch the demos and even my own hello-world apps on a Raspberry Pi 3B.

I have two problems that do not seem to have any good answers on the web at this point:

1. Cntrl+C rarely exits a kivy app.  Reboot required.
2. The mouse cursor is never visible unless I add the [module] line to set:
             touchring = show_cursor=true (this only provides a circle on mouse or finger down. No mouse tracking or display.

No Kivy app runs properly windowed.  They all show up full screen with no frame or the typical minimize/max/close buttons.

Is this the typical PI experience? Or are there fixes out there I just have not found?

Appreciate any advice!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is typical kivy experience. Best is to completely exit the desktop environment and use the command line environment and start your kivy app from there.

Have you tried something like

```
try:
    MyApp().run()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print('exciting due to Keyboard')
    App.get_running_app().stop()
```

The `App.get_running_app().stop()` might not even be neccessary.